# geographic description of coastal rock formation

Tags: description

Hello masters of geographic eloquence,

A rock arch bridges across to a rock formation 
seen in the screen right of the image/photograph. 
It's not an independent 'island'. 
What word(s) best describe this isolated rock outcrop ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image: coast]

(credit due to unknown photographer of this image)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Marty, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  I'm not sure this is the right place for this question.  If you're asking for geology terms...  If you just want plain English description, I dont' see a bridge, I see a rock formation with a passageway.

Comment: Hi Marty, like your other question, this is a request for a single word or phrase, which is off-topic for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That formation is called an [arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_arch), and it connects what may soon become a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(geology)) to the main coastline. The key points of both archs and stacks is that they form by erosion.

In contrast, a peninsula is **typically** a larger landmass formed by accretion or alternative means other than erosion. Italy is a peninsula, to give an example.

The links:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_arch
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(geology)

Comment: Apologies for the off topic questions.
'Stack' is the word I was searching for. 
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is 'peninsula'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peninsula

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site! Looks like a fitting term. Could you copy the relevant parts of the linked wikipedia article here? Links can rot away, which would leave your answer currently without any justification for why this is correct. The goal of StackExchange is to help everyone with a similar question in the future without the need to search somewhere else. That's why everything should be in the answer and links should only support if someone wants to learn even more about the topic. If you write an ">" in front of it the system will render it as a quote. Have fun on the site!